# Quiero que el programa de un clic en forma automática al primer renglón que encuentra en la consulta

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código, lo que hace es mostrarme las coincidencias de lo que escribo, lo que necesito es que una vez que encuentre las coincidencias le dé un clic en forma automática al primer renglón de la tabla, como el ejemplo de abajo

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
            $("#descripcion").autocomplete({
                source: "productos.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#codigo').val(ui.item.codigo);
          $('#descripcion').val(ui.item.descripcion);
          $('#precio').val(ui.item.precio);
          $('#id_producto').val(ui.item.id_producto);
           }

            });
          $("#cantidad").focus();
    });

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una vez encontraste la coincidencia, como esta es la primera que aparece en la lista, busque el primer elemento `<li>` con la clase que usted usa, con el metodo [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$( ".miClase" ).each(function( index ) {
  if (index == 0) {
      $(this).click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Eso es darle un clic al input cantidad y lo que quiero es darle un clic al primer renglón de la tabla que se muestra

Comment: Puedes adjuntar como se ve el html de la lista?

Comment: $return_arr = array();


if ($link)
{
 $fetch = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Articulos0001 where Razon like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_GET['term'])) . "%' order by Razon LIMIT 0 ,50"); 
 
 

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {

  $id_producto=$row['id'];
  
  
  $row_array['value'] =  $row['IdClave']." | ".$row['Razon']; 
  $row_array['id_producto']=$row['id'];
  $row_array['codigo']=$row['IdClave'];
  $row_array['descripcion']=$row['Razon'];
  $row_array['precio']=$precio;

  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
  

    }

}

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, fijate si te ayuda